# ExtJS tabpanel form field focus

Tags: forms, extjs, tabs, focus, setfocus

I have a tabbed panel which each tab as a form with some textfields on each of those forms.
I want a way to focus on the first field of the form of the tab, each time a tab is clicked.
I know how to set focus a field but I want the focus to be when the corresponding tab is clicked.
Someone that have done this can tell me how do you do that?
I have tried the **tabpanel** event *tabchange*, it works but it doesn't set focus on the first field; I have tried each **tab** events *click*, *show*, *focus*, *activate* but they don't seem to work. I don't know what else to do.
Someone that has already done this can please tell me how do they have done it?
Thank you

Here is an image of the tabpanel:
[image: TabPanel with Forms]

Comment: the command that I use for focus is `tabpanel.down('#tab').down('#firstfield').focus()`, so I'm not messing up on that

Answer (score 3):

All it has to be done is:

```
listeners: {
    tabchange: function(tabPanel, newCard) {
        setTimeout(function(){ newCard.down('#firstfield').focus(); },10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following and it works fine for me.

```
xtype: 'tabpanel',
listeners: {
    tabchange: function(tabPanel, newCard) { //Activate the field.
        try{
            if(newCard){
                var txtField = newCard.down('#TxtField');
                if(txtField){
                    txtField.focus();
                }
            }
        }catch(err){ //ignore.
        }
    }
}
```

Note:- This code works only for given #TxtField to get the focus.